# I am linking a background image in my CSS but it is not appearing. Any idea what the problem is?

Tags: css

I have a bit of code that looks like this:

```
<style>
  #block {
    opacity: 1.0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url("file:///Users/myname/Desktop/Coding/person.png");
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  </style>
```

I got this file path from right clicking the file then clicking "Open in Chrome" then copying the file path in the search bar. When I press F12 to see the dev tools, and go to the div this is linked up to, it shows a preview of the image I want to use when I hover over the file name. But on the actual file, it doesn't show anything. Also, I know that the problem isn't with the div because when I change it to a background color, rather than an image, it shows perfectly.

Comment: where is your html code?

Comment: Create a folder called images in your project root directory. copy and paste the image to the newly created folder (images) then change the `url` to `/images/person.png` or `./images/person.png`

Comment: @Mech <div id="block"class="block"></div>

Comment: You can't load background images from `file://` URLs.

Comment: I've tried all of these. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <style>
  #block {
              opacity: 1.0;
              width: 50px;
              height: 50px;
              background-image: url(person.png);
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              margin-top: 0px;
              margin-left: 0px;
            }
  </style>
  </head>          
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Unfortunately bro file:///Users/myname/Desktop/Coding/person.png is not a valid link. Try getting the image you want on its assets folder found in the sources in devtools.